# object of an abstract class c++ as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following code:

```
class Region {
public:
    virtual Region* clone() const = 0;
    virtual ~Region() {}
    bool contains(double x, double y) const = 0;
}

class UnionRegion : public Region {
    shared_ptr<Region> r1;
    shared_ptr<Region> r2;
public:
    UnionRegion(const Region& r1, const Region& r2) :
           r1(r1.clone()), r2(r2.clone()) {}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

`Region` is an abstract class. I do not understand how the ctor of `UnionRegion` can receive an object of type `Region`, because how can we create an object of an abstract class?

Also what is the point of holding a `shared_ptr` to `Region`? I understand that because `Region` is abstract we need a pointer, but `Region` doesn't even have private members, so basically I can do nothing with that pointer.

Thanks!

Comment: But it takes a **reference...** No actual instance is created, no copy is performed. The function just takes whatever concrete object it is passed.

Comment: Reference to an object is not an object. I always thought references to be just glorified pointers.

Comment: @j_kubik That's wrong, references are not pointers, and a reference **is** the object. (It's *exactly* that it's not a **copy** but the object itself.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I know it is - but it doesn't even need the type to be fully defined to use it. In most cases if you can use pointer to it, you can also have a reference to it. And since pointers are most typical implementation for references, the difference (while existing) is not that big.

Comment: @j_kubik A more precise naming for the behavior you describe would be that "regarding some aspects, references have pointer-like semantics".

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, yes... "It's exactly that it's not a copy but the object itself." - I understand that reference to an object is not a copy. I don't know exact wording used in standard, but I see a logical difference between object itself and a reference to it. You cannot say that reference is an object - it's a reference to one. It's like a difference between a book and it's entry in library catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can we create an object of an abstract class?

You **can not** create an object of an abstract class, you can only use abstract class reference/pointer which refer to derived concrete class objects.

> what is the point of holding a shared_ptr to Region?

If you want a class member which its concrete type is unknown, yo have to use pointer or reference to hold it. *Then later you can invoke override virtual functions to have polymorphism actions.*

The one which need to negotiate is: why your UnionRegion which is a derived type need to hold a pointer(shared_ptr) to its base? It's more like design behavior.

Answer (score 1):

`Region` is an abstract class, but it is never instantiated. A reference to `const Region` binds to an object of any subclass of `Region` (much as a pointer to `const Region` would). So `UnionRegion`'s constructor takes references to any two objects that are subclasses of `Region`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UnionRegion` inherits from `Region` the `UnionRegion(const Region& r1, const Region& r2)` can be called with either other `UnionRegion`parameters or any other class type which inherits from `Region`. Since this is a constructor I assume there might be also some other class type which inherits from `Region` and is used to construct `UnionRegion`.